# Python "Incorrect padding" error when doing base64-urlsafe decoding

Tags: python, base64

I am trying to base64 decode 2 strings (urlsafe) using `base64.urlsafe_b64decode(s)`, but I kept getting the "Incorrect padding" error. I can't show the 2 strings, but I can briefly describe them.

- First string: 131 characters long, contains non-urlsafe characters
- Second string: 115 characters long, contains non-urlsafe characters

The function was able to decode other strings containing non-urlsafe characters, so I assume that's not the problem and these characters are removed prior to decoding.

I tried adding `===` to both strings to make sure it's not a lack of `=` padding problem, but it didn't work. I was only able to decode when I removed the last character from the string, and it worked regardless of whether the `=` padding exists, i.e. the 130-character string without padding was decodable. However, when I tried to decode using CyberChef, I was able to decode both original strings. I'm not really comfortable with removing the last character, as the decoded string also lost the last character, and that doesn't seem like the right solution.

I don't understand what the difference is between using the `base64` function to decode and what CyberChef does. How can I resolve this using `base64`?

Comment: in both cases you would only need one `=` to make it a multiple of 4. And why did you use b64urldecode when it's obviously not url safe encoded?

Comment: You’ve given counts of 131 and 115, but how many of those are meaningful base64 characters? If the count is 1 mod 4, that’d be the problem, and I’d ask what encoded the strings (and how they came to have non-meaningful characters interspersed).

Comment: @Ry- I just read about "non-urlsafe" characters, so I guess it's just normal Base64, not Base64 url

Comment: @Ry- In the 115-ch string, 113 are meaningful base64-url characters. I removed the 2 non-base64url characters, added 3 '=' padding, but still get the incorrect padding error.

Comment: @jps I was told the strings are url safe encoded. In fact, the strings contain '-' and '_'. The non-urlsafe characters I mentioned are not in the alphabet set of base64 or base64-url. I thought the library would just remove the non-alphabet characters and decode, like CyberChef.

Comment: @Rayne ok, I understand. But if you remove the 2 'garbage` characters and try with the remaining 113 it means you have 112*6/8 = 84 bytes + 6 bits from character no. 113. Then either there is still one character too much or one more meaningful character + 2 "="  (result:  85 bytes) or two meaningful characters + 1"=" (result: 86 bytes) are missing. 3 padding chars are simply wrong. When Cyberchef can 'handle' your string, it's just guessing or trying to rescue as much as possible from an essentially broken input. To guess data is IMHO not a good strategy.